# Save Checkboxes state in ListView and Retrieve it back when come back to class using Shared preferences

Tags: android

I Got stucked in saving the Checkboxes state and getting back in listview, i want to save what all the items were checked and save it and get it back when the Activity is called again... Pls help me in this with sample code... any help will be very usefull for me.

Comment: You just have to read android documentation for working with Shared preferences and activity life cycle. I would recommend saving check box state each time the state is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code(But not using sharedPreferences)

```
    public class SavedInstanceDemo extends Activity{

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //retrieve values from savedInstanceState

            Boolean isChecked=savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isChecked",false);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
            //save your requires values into this outState which can be retrieved on next time
            outState.putBoolean("isChecked", true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: HI Sai Mukesh I tried your code but it thros Null Pointer Exception for me, lvUsers = getListView();
  lvUsers.setItemsCanFocus(false);
  lvUsers.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); this is the wy iam geting the action for CB's, iam populating the listview from the DB using Adapter class, for clarity iam jst getting the id os the item when clicks on the listItem and checks the cb and iam using it, fine, those id's were handled if once again come back to the page and reselects again, but i am unable t shoe\w the checked one as checked one unchecked as unchecked...

Comment: Boolean isChecked=savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isChecked",false); Initially there will be no value when the application is installed. Sou you need to pass a defaultValue

Comment: I think in this case the default value is unchecked isn't it?

Comment: could you pls help me if i post you the class file... if yes pls tell me how can i attach my class file here